# Is there any app like Trackma for Movies in ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am using [Trackma](https://z411.github.io/trackma/) + [Kitsu](https://kitsu.io/) for tracking anime list.But Trackma supports Kitsu,VNDB,Anilist only.

Now I am searching for something like that for Movie list.Anything that runs on ubuntu will be ok.
Purpose: Maintain Movie watch list.

Required:
**Preferred Toolkit**: Gtk/Qt
**Auto Sync Support**

**Trackma** **Features:**

- Manage local list and synchronize with web (VNDB/Kitsu/Anilist) when necessary, useful when offline
- Detection of running media player, updates list if necessary
- Ability to launch media player for a requested media in the list and update list if necessary

Comment: You'll have to improve your description - how are we expected to know what features of Trackma+Kitsu (whatever they are) you need.

Comment: Qusetion was Updated.